# Print exact word after 2 match patterns

Tags: linux

This is my input command -

```
tmsh list auth user all | egrep 'auth|role' | sed 'N;s/\n/,/' > users.csv
```

I get the following output -

```
auth user jen {,            role admin
auth user john {,            role user
```

I want only the exact user and role to be printed in a table -
[image]

Could someone please help me with this?

Is it possible to enter the header "user" and "role" as well?

Comment: Could you please  share within your questions the raw output of: `tmsh list auth user all`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that I don't have `tmsh` and no raw sample data was provided this is very much guesswork.

```
tmsh list auth user all | awk '/^auth/{printf "%s,",$3} /role/{print $2}' > users.csv
```